# When are we going to have STS (Spring Tool Suite) that supports JDK 8

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-tool-suite

Just wanted to know how soon are we going to have a STS release that supports JDK 8

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be directed at the Spring developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STS does support JDK 8. See [this announcement](http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v351/NewAndNoteworthy.html) for 3.5.1 version.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, A simple Google search didn't reveal a straightforward answer.